# How to use find() with findIndex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have a small problem regarding Array to find Elements using find() with findIndex. I have demo code which is worked when I am using only find() method with my array variable.

```
    var a = [{
      _id: 'newlead',
      count: 45
    }, {
      _id: 'contact',
      count: 12
    }, {

    leadCount: [{
          _id: 'newlead',
          count: 45
        }, {
          _id: 'contact',
          count: 12
        }]
    }]

var findElement = a.find(a => {
  return a._id === 'newlead'
});

console.log(findElement);
```

The actual problem is I want to check in an array, '**leadCount**' is exist or not, if exist then I am doing this, I have a code. this code throws an error **"TypeError: a.findIndex(...).find is not a function**

```
let data = a.findIndex( element => {
  return 'leadCount' in element
}).find(e => {
    return e._id === 'newlead'
})

console.log(data)
```

Please suggest me the right thing.

thank you

Comment: Why are you using `findIndex` instead of `find`?

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: I need this object inside data variable `{
          _id: 'newlead',
          count: 45
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
 var a = [{
  _id: 'newlead',
  count: 45
}, {
  _id: 'contact',
  count: 12
}, {

leadCount: [{
      _id: 'newlead',
      count: 45
    }, {
      _id: 'contact',
      count: 12
    }]
}];



let data = a.find(e => 'leadCount' in e) || {leadCount: []}.leadCount.find(e => e._id === 'newlead')

console.log(data)
```